# Window function with 0 values in database

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=023da82748934380a9fec11dba9f9c76)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    sales DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, country, sales)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', '500'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', '900'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', '700'),

('2020-03-20', 'DE', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'FR', '0'),
('2020-03-20', 'NL', '0'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', '800'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', '100');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date  |  country  |    sales_share_per_country_per_day    |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-02-08  |    DE     |     0.24  (=500/2100)                 |  
2020-02-08  |    FR     |     0.43  (=900/2100)                 |
2020-02-08  |    NL     |     0.33  (=700/2100)                 |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-03-20  |    DE     |     0.33                              |
2020-03-20  |    FR     |     0.33                              |
2020-03-20  |    NL     |     0.33                              |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-04-15  |    DE     |     0.25  (=300/1200)                 |
2020-04-15  |    FR     |     0.67  (=800/1200)                 |
2020-04-15  |    NL     |     0.08  (=100/1100)                 |
```

---

I am using a Window function to get the `sales_share_per_country_per_day.` 
As you can see on `2020-03-20` there are no sales so I am getting a `division by zero` error.

---

In order to avoid this error I implemented a `CASE WHEN` function. 
In case the sales are zero the sales_share should be equivalent to the numbers of countries. 
However, currently the query displays a `0` for the `2020-03-20` instead of `0.33`. 
How do I need to modify the below query to make it work correctly?

```
SELECT
s.event_date,
s.country,
s.sales,

(CASE WHEN SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date) = 0 THEN 
100/(COUNT(s.country) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date))/100
ELSE s.sales/SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date) END) AS share_per_day_per_country

FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0f1ac224ad8d06524994ec4cc6cdfefd)

This:

```
100/(COUNT(s.country) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date))/100
```

returns an `integer` value because you are dividing by two `integer` values (`COUNT()` returns an integer value and `100`, of course is one, too). So, you should cast at least one of both parts into type `decimal` or `numeric`:

```
100/(COUNT(s.country) OVER (PARTITION BY s.event_date))/100::numeric
```

or simply divide by `100.0` instead of `100`.